# I can't eas build --platform android Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'

Tags: build, expo, eas

In my expo sdk version 47, when I eas build in root directory it shows Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
how will i solve?

my app.json folder is

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "ebibaaha",
    "slug": "ebibaaha",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.ebibaaha.app",
      "permissions": [
        "CAMERA",
        "CAMERA_ROLL"
      ]
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "97cd307d-920a-4056-a550-0770aa4afaef"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjvi9.png)

I tried eas build --platform android to build my expo react native app but it show error.

Comment: my error in image description

Comment: Try adding `"versionCode":1"` to your android object